# valid value for COL and TAB of btitle command of SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

What can be a valid value for COL and TAB of btitle command of SQL*Plus ?

From a help I can not find anything about the `n`

```
SQL> help btitle

BTITLE
------

Places and formats a specified title at the bottom of each report
page, or lists the current BTITLE definition.

BTI[TLE] [printspec [text|variable] ...] | [OFF|ON]

where printspec represents one or more of the following clauses:

     COL n          LE[FT]        BOLD
     S[KIP] [n]     CE[NTER]      FORMAT text
     TAB n          R[IGHT]


SQL>

SQL> show btitle
btitle OFF and is the first few characters of the next SELECT statement
SQL> btitle tab 239 test
SQL> sho btitle
btitle ON and is the following 18 characters:
tab 239 test
SQL> btitle tab 240 test
SQL> sho btitle
btitle ON and is the following 18 characters:
tab 240 test
SQL> btitle tab 241 test
Invalid COL or TAB position entered
SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

> What can be a valid value for COL and TAB of btitle command of SQL*Plus ?

It is all [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12010.htm):

> BTITLE
>
> Syntax
>
> BTI[TLE] [printspec [text | variable] ...] | [ON | OFF]
>
> where printspec represents one or more of the following clauses used
>   to place and format the text:
>
> BOLD
>
> CE[NTER]
>
> COL n
>
> FORMAT text
>
> LE[FT]
>
> R[IGHT]
>
> S[KIP] [n]
>
> TAB n
>
> Places and formats a specified title at the bottom of each report
>   page, or lists the current BTITLE definition.

Let's see an example:

- To set a **bottom title** with **CORPORATE PLANNING DEPARTMENT** on the **left** and a **date** on the **right**:

```
SQL> BTITLE LEFT 'CORPORATE PLANNING DEPARTMENT' - RIGHT '1 JAN 2001'
SQL> SELECT * FROM dual;

D
-
X









CORPORATE PLANNING DEPARTMENT-                                        1 JAN 2001

SQL>
```

- To set a **bottom title** with **CONFIDENTIAL** in **column 50**, followed by **six spaces** and a **date**:

```
SQL> BTITLE COL 50 'CONFIDENTIAL' TAB 6 '1 JAN 2001'
SQL> SELECT * FROM dual;

D
-
X









                                                 CONFIDENTIAL      1 JAN 2001

SQL>
```

**Update** OP wants to know why setting **TAB** value exceeding `240` throws an error.

The reason is that the **LINESIZE** is less and thus it doesn't let the TAB go beyond 240. Increasing the linesize will work.

For example,

```
SQL> set linesize 240
SQL> btitle tab 241 test
Invalid COL or TAB position entered
```

Let's increase the **linesize**:

```
SQL> set linesize 241
SQL> btitle tab 241 test
SQL>
```

The limit `240` comes from the maximum length limit of **CHAR**.

From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm),

> CHAR
>
> Makes the datatype of variable the datatype CHAR. The maximum CHAR
>   length limit is 240 bytes. If a multi-byte character set is used, one
>   CHAR may be more than one byte in size.

So, even if you increase the linesize beyond 240, **BTITLE TAB** can't go beyond 240 due to the maximum length limit of **CHAR** which is `240`.

For example,

```
SQL> btitle tab 241 ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
*****************************************
string beginning "**********..." is too long. maximum size is 240 characters.
SQL> btitle tab 241 ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
***************************************
Invalid COL or TAB position entered
SQL> set linesize 241
SQL> btitle tab 241 ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
***************************************
SQL> select * from dual;

D
-
X











SQL>
```

As you can see above, `string beginning "**********..." is too long. maximum size is 240 characters.` Even after increasing the linesize to 241, **BTITLE** cannot place and format the text.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it in the documentation. But why it is invalid when I set col to 241 in my example ?

Comment: @user2018791 Because your `LINESIZE` is not letting the `TAB` to set beyond `240`. Increase the linesize. See my updated answer.

Comment: But 240 is valid when linesize is the default 80.

Comment: @user2018791 Actually that limit is the maximum length of **CHAR**. See my update.

Comment: @user2018791 Please mark it as answered, would help others.